# disable a specific network or wifi interface conveniently

Tags: linux, power-management, xfce, networkmanager

I have a laptop with an unfortunately weak wifi card. For that reason, I recently bought a USB dongle with an external antenna.

- Ubuntu LTS with the xfce desktop is used.
- The internal, fixed wifi (`wlp1s0` in ifconfig -a) is still useful, even if it requires much greater signal strength. It should only be used when the USB wifi is not connected.
- The USB wifi (`wlx003` in ifconfig -a) is less convenient, so it is only used on an as-needed-basis.
- That laptop is frequently used by non-expert users.

I am looking for a way to conveniently manage (disable/enable/connect/...) the two cards. NetworkManager does not seem to have a "completely switch this card off" feature (or I have not found it?)...

I realize that the case of having to manage two Wifi NICs is rare.

I want to stress that it is **all about the convenient and easy GUI part**, and at the moment NetworkManager manages these things. The answer to the question should not be hard to do for non-expert users (that practically means **no shell**).

Comment: Are the two devices configured to use different interfaces?  Could you set up one on eth1 and the other on eth2 and toggle things by turning on or off the interfaces?

Comment: I have amended the question. They always use different interface designations. It's more about the GUI part. if you turn off (like `ifconfig wlp1s0 down`) a networkmanager-managed interface, networkmanager will turn it on again.

Comment: You could write a shell script and then link it to a desktop icon.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/141229/how-to-add-a-shell-script-to-launcher-as-shortcut

Comment: I know I can do that. I am looking for palatable existing(! I do not have to maintain anything by the time I forget how it did, when my phone rings with the problem) solutions with proper error handling that do not freak out people using this laptop. If there is nothing already, I probably will go down that route.